# Call function from another function in jQuery OOP

Tags: jquery, function, oop, timer, call

I have a jQuery function like this, written in OOP style:

```
$.fn.myscript = {

        timer: '',

start: function(duration){

            var x = 0;

    timer = setInterval(function(){

        x++;

    }, 1000);

},

    stop: function(){

        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

First, I call `start` function, and then timer starts to work. But when İ call `stop` function it shows error. What is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.timer` instead of just `timer` in both calls :

```
$.fn.myscript = {
    timer: '',
    start: function(duration){
         var x = 0;
         this.timer = setInterval(function(){
             x++;
         }, 1000);
    },
    stop: function(){
        this.clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
}
```

---

Supposing you use x and you want to be able to pause and resume, here's how your code could  be :

```
$.fn.myscript = {
    timer: 0, x: 0,
    start: function(duration){ // do both start and resume
         this.timer = setInterval(function(){
             this.x++;
         }, 1000);
    },
    stop: function(){
        this.x = 0;
        this.clearInterval(this.timer);
    },
    pause: function(){
        this.clearInterval(this.timer);
    },
    getX: function(){ // use this to get access to x
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov When I edited, I forgot one of those `this.`. Sorry (and thanks for Laurynas).

Comment: thanks very much! But it worked without "this" before clearInterval. Now, I have second question for you: I don't want to stop timer, I just want to PAUSE timer. How can I do it?

Comment: How are you using x ? Right now, as you don't use it, there's no difference between pause/resume and stop/start.

Comment: Yes, I know, I need to use x without making it equal to zero again and again. Where I must put var x = o? before `start` function, yes?

Comment: better use your timer as a separate object. will have less pain when you decide to have more than one timer at once ;)